# Reverse engineer assembler which probably encrypts code?

Tags: assembly, encryption, reverse-engineering

I use an IDE with integrated assembler to write code for microcontrollers of a company which also produces the IDE and assembler I just mentioned.
Because the development kit with hardware in-circuit programmer is quite expensive I would like to reverse engineer their way of assembling the written source-code into the file format which is later transferred to the controller via the programming device.

So basically what I did was writing a very basic assembly program (like this):

```
mov a, 0x01
```

and changed very little of it (like this):

```
mov a, 0x02
```

then I took a look at the generated files in binary format. What I expected was not even close to what was actually happening:

Not only a single byte changed (what I was hoping for) but 2000 bytes of a total of 2300 changed!

The methods which would be possible to do this are either encryption or compression, or maybe both combined.

Is it possible to decrypt or decompress the files even though I have no idea what algorithm they are using?

Comment: why not just get the datasheet for the part in question and read about what the programming interface is as well as the processor, etc.  if it is 100% closed and secret then dont bother move onto some more interesting part.

Comment: what is the part in question?

Comment: There neither is documentation about the programming interface nor the assembler, maybe because the company is only known in taiwan and not in europe / USA. The company is called Padauk: http://www.padauk.com.tw/products.php?item=14
I am wondering how the PicKit was cloned by chinese people because, as far as I know, the programming interface for PIC controller is also closed source.

Comment: This question is too broad for the StackOverflow format. There are too many possible answers, and all come down to "if you are trying to break someone else's system, you will have to reverse engineer it." It is not possible to decrypt or decompress data if you don't know the algorithm. You will have to determine the algorithm. You have algorithm available (the compiler); you will have to reverse engineer how it works if you want to attack it.

Comment: If you want to discuss reverse engineering more generally, the best forum is https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You talking about Microchip PIC?  Which controllers are not documented?  They dont have the best documentation for sure, but they have enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not assume the most complex answer to your questions; instead, always look for the simplest explanation of what you see. Why going all the way to encrypting and stuff when vendor's low market share and lack of documentation do almost as good job in keeping secrets? Adding encryption (and decryption in hardware!) will cost the vendor (a lot of) money.

It may simply be the case that the two instructions you used are very different, and also that your tools calculated difference incorrectly.

`mov a, 0x1` may be encoded as `inc a`, which might be, let's imagine, one byte long, and `mov a, 0x2` may be representable as a two byte machine instruction. After that all the subsequent bytes will be offset to one position in files being compared, and, if your comparison tools cannot accommodate for that, they will report a huge difference.

In general, it is possible to reverse things. It will be very time consuming, an undertaking proportionally big to the size of instruction set and to number of features the binary format you are studying.

Essentially, you want reconstruct the layout of a binary format, and machine encoding scheme. Providing minimally different inputs and looking at outputs is a correct first thing to do; but you cannot make conclusions just after a single experiment. It is simply not enough data collected.

If you are really decided to jump into this, I recommend you to start from studying papers, tools and approaches used by people for solving similar cases. Hackme tutorials, papers on reversing etc. Be prepared that it will take you a least several months before you could get first results. It is fun, but not always a well-paid activity.

Comment: I also did several tests with higher numbers like `mov a,0x11` `mov a,0x12` and they were all quite different (2000 bytes to be specific).